# cant return value out of closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to get this value to pass the isValid value back out of the ajax call in the snippet below:

```
    function isShortUrlAvailable(sender, args) {
        var isValid = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/App_Services/ShortUrlService.asmx/IsUrlAvailable",
            data: "{url: '" + args.Value + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                isValid = response.d;
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        args.IsValid = isValid;
    }
```

I'm sure its just something simple to do with closures that i'm overlooking. Can anyone help please?

Its for an asp.net custom validator.

This is what's happening:

1. isValid is set to false in the first line
2. .ajax() request fires correctly and if its valid returns true
3. isValid is set to true (response.d) correctly
4. when it comes back out to the last line it thinks isValid is false again

Comment: short answer you can't return the value since ajax is asynchronous, you need to use a callback to solve this problem

Comment: You can't : your callback is executed only after the external function returns.

Comment: Can you share how the method is used?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in an `<asp:CustomValidator>` but you pass the value back to the customvalidator by setting the args.IsValid and its not getting it.

Comment: I seem to have solved it with async: false but I've read this is deprecated in future versions of jQuery and also "a-bad-idea"

Comment: Thanks for closing my question, I solved it and was most of the way through replying to my own question with examples and reasons behind the issue. Now I can't post it for others to learn from. If the other "duplicates" answered my question I would have said that wouldn't I! :(

Answer (score 1):

AJAX methods are **asynchronous** meaning that you're value is set to `false`, the AJAX call is started, but whilst it's happening the `args.IsValid` line is called. Just remove the variable and set the `args.IsValid` value in each scenario:

```
function isShortUrlAvailable(sender, args) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/App_Services/ShortUrlService.asmx/IsUrlAvailable",
        data: "{url: '" + args.Value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            args.IsValid = response.d;
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve it. I was setting it that way for a while and it still didnt pass it back up the chain. I'd only changed it to the posted code just before as I read another example that I thought might be the solution.